# Delphi reaching a DBGrid's rows

Tags: delphi, rows, dbgrid

So i have a TDBGrid, my purpose is searching DBGrid's Fieldname and comparing it with my Edit's Text property and if they are equal then,

i want to write the whole column which i've found the match, to a ListBox.

With a for loop with fieldcount, i can compare FieldName, though since there is no rows or rowcount property i can use, i don't know how i would get the index of this whole column.

```
for i:=0 to DBGrid1.FieldCount-1 do
begin
 if DBGrid1.Fields[i].FieldName=Edit1.Text then
   for j:=1 to DBGrid1.RowCount-1 do
     ListBox1.Items.Add(DBGrid1.Rows.Fields[i].Index.AsString);
end;
```

This is an imaginary code of what im trying to do...

P.S.:I'm still using Delphi 7, (educational reasons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the row values directly from the DbGrid. Instead, you have to navigate through the dataset that's used to feed the DbGrid.

This example assumes you are using a `TClientDataSet`.

```
for i := 0 to DBGrid1.FieldCount - 1 do
begin
  if DBGrid1.Fields[i].FieldName = Edit1.Text then
  begin
    ClientDataSet1.DisableControls;
    try
      ClientDataSet1.First();
      while (not ClientDataSet1.Eof) do
      begin
        ListBox1.Items.Add(ClientDataSet1.FieldByName(Edit1.Text).AsString);
        ClientDataSet1.Next();
      end;
    finally
      ClientDataSet1.EnableControls;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as DBGrid only displays an excerpt of the data, IMHO you should

- get a bookmark of your dataset
- disable Controls
- use first, while not eof with your dataset, adding
  Dataset.FieldbyName(Edit1.text).asString to your list
- goto bookmark
- enable controls